# clonar un selectpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buenas Tardes amigos tengo el siguiente problema necesito clonar un selectpicker múltiple el cual lo tengo en un DOM con un formulario incremetable que esta dentro de una tabla html, el problema es que al agregar otra fila el selectpicker me aparecen dos veces, uno que funciona y otro clonado que no funciona, lo que quiero es que cuando le doy mas, para otra fila, pues que selectpicker me deje selecionar y no me clone la primera fila ya registrada 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
      <td><label>Descripción</label>
      <input type="text" name="descripcion[]"  class="form-control" placeholder="Descripcion de la Actividad"/></textarea></td>


      <td><label>R. Ejecución</label>
      <br/>
      <select class="selectpicker"  name="usuario[]" data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" multiple="">
      <option>

      <option></option>


      <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario ORDER BY nombre ASC";
      $registros=mysql_query($query,$conexion) or die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($registros)){
      $usuario=$row['usuario'];
      $nombre=$row['nombre'];


      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $usuario;?>"><?php echo $nombre;?></option>

      <?php }?>

      </select>
      </td>



      <td>

      <div class="col-md-16">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fecha Inicio:</label>
      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
      <input type="text" name="fecha_inicio[]" size="12"  class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!--
      <div class="col-xs-5">   
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fecha Fin:</label>
      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
      <input type="text" name="fecha_final[]"  class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      -->

      <input type="hidden" name="fecha_final[]" value="<?php echo date("j-n-Y") ?>">

      <td class="eliminar"><p></p><input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="Menos -"/></td>

      </tr>



      </table>
      <div class="btn-der">

      <button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-info"> Más + </button>
```

> Este seria el codigo Javascript donde genero el clon del formulario que esta dentro de la tabla html donde tengo el problema con el selectpicker

```
<script>

      $(function(){

      // Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de la tabla
      clon = $("#tabla");
      tr = $('tr:first', clon);
      $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
      tr.clone().appendTo(clon).find(':text').val('');
      clon.find(".date").datetimepicker();
      clon.find('select').selectpicker();




      });
      // Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
      $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
      var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
      $(parent).remove();
      });





      });
      </script>
```

Comment: Revisá el código HTML que genera el selectpicker. Es probable que lo duplique y lo oculte. Cuando vos duplicás a mano la fila, estás copiando el selectpicker "original" y el duplicado. Al clonar deberías eliminar el que no funciona. Publicá el código HTML original y el que genera el selectpicker así te orientamos mejor.

Comment: ya te publico el código html

Comment: Para agregar contenido o actualizaciones a tu pregunta, realizalo con el botón "editar". @AlexisLozada

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia  Jorgesys ya edite bien la pregunta